# How to release http.Client in Go?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I built a `http.Client` for HTTP2 connection, what do I need to do to release the client and resource used?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`http.Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) does not require any special way to free "used" resources. When it becomes unreachable, memory used by it will be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

`http.Client` does not store connection or state information. The documentation even states that `http.Client` should be reused:

> The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

If you build your own client using (e.g. embedding) `http.Client` and you allocate resources that must be released explicitly, provide your own `Close()` method on it and document that anyone who uses your own implementation must call `Close()` if it is not needed anymore.

**Note:**

What you might confuse it with is that if you use an `http.Client` to do HTTP operations (like [`Client.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do), [`Client.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get), [`Client.Post()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Post) etc.), they return a value of [`*http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response), and that response does hold a connection, state and other resources, which **does** need to be freed, typically via `Response.Body.Close()`. Quoting from the package doc of `http`:

> The client must close the response body when finished with it:
>
> ```
> resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
> if err != nil {
>   // handle error
> }
> defer resp.Body.Close()
> body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
> // ...
> ```

It is also documented at `Client.Get()`:

> When err is nil, resp always contains a non-nil resp.Body. Caller should close resp.Body when done reading from it.

Comment: The client dose not need any special function call, but if the response.Body is used (the result of calling Do, or Get/Post/... functions) , you must close it with `resp.Body.Close()`

Comment: @fzerorubigd But that is not a method of `http.Client`, and it has nothing to do with `http.Client`. It does not free any resources related to `http.Client` but resources related to the connection.

Comment: I know. and I said that. but this is the common pitfall in using http.Client anyway (done this once) and I think it's not a bad idea to mention it here :)

Answer (score 5):

The `CloseIdleConnections()` method was added in Go 1.12.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.CloseIdleConnections

> CloseIdleConnections closes any connections on its Transport which were previously connected from previous requests but are now sitting idle in a "keep-alive" state. It does not interrupt any connections currently in use.