# Best way to use HTTP client in a concurrent application

Tags: http, go, concurrency, goroutine

First I'll describe my case.
I have to do HTTPS requests to several APIs from my application and they should be ran concurrently.
I want to know if I should use a separate HTTP client per goroutine or I can share one client across all goroutines. Of course I'd like to enjoy connection reusing/pooling offered by the HTTP client, but I am concerned about it being thread(aka goroutine)-safe and if the client will run requests concurrently or they'll in fact be sequenced?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to release http.Client in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688633/how-to-release-http-client-in-go)

Answer (score 35):

Http clients are thread safe according to the docs (https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go):

> Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Comment: If goroutines are so many,  will a single client become bottleneck ??

Comment: Yes same question, what if there are 1000s of goroutines using a single global client variable?

Comment: @user4867444 please could you explain to us: why it won't be a bottleneck?

Comment: Simply because it doesn't have any locks

Comment: @user4867444 - Firstly, the question is a perfectly reasonable one. Second, SO is a place for questions, where people help others _understand_ how these things work. Third, you might not understand how this works, as there _are_ locks in the http.Client. The `RoundTripper` is an interface, which by default uses `http.Transport`. This has `atleast 3 mutexe`s without going into more subfields. Next, the cookie jar - `http.Jar`, again... has a mutex.

There are infact multiple locks, and this question is not only valid, but it's also entirely possible to have an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

The other question was should you use one client or one per request. You should use one client as per
https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-overview

"Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used"